# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).multiselect is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-multiselect

I don't know what I'm doing wrong but I get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).multiselect is not a function
>
> at HTMLDocument. (Register:715)
>
> at fire (jquery-1.10.2.js:3062)
>
> at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.10.2.js:3174)
>
> at Function.ready (jquery-1.10.2.js:447)
>
> at HTMLDocument.completed (jquery-1.10.2.js:118)

HTML

```
<!-- Include Twitter Bootstrap and jQuery: -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Include the plugin's CSS and JS: -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/bootstrap-multiselect.css" type="text/css" />

<!--Example-->
<select id="example-getting-started" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="cheese">Cheese</option>
    <option value="tomatoes">Tomatoes</option>
    <option value="mozarella">Mozzarella</option>
</select>
```

Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example-getting-started').multiselect();
    });
<script>
```

Comment: link this css <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css"/> after bootstap.min.js

Comment: @SanjitBhardwaj I just tried but It doesn't work

Comment: All js files loaded or any 404's?

Comment: What is the version of bootstrap-multiselect.js?

Comment: @RakeshMakluri All loaded...

Comment: You have or wrong versions or wrong paths to the files, because using CDN path in a fiddle, it works well, take a look: https://jsfiddle.net/qzcufk27/

Comment: @CalvinNunes The path to the files are correct and how can I get the bootstrap equivalent of jquery 1.10.2 version?

Comment: there is no bootstrap-multiselect 1.10.2 the latest version is 0.9.15

Comment: @CalvinNunes Could it be possible that the jquery version was not compatible with the bootstrap version?

Comment: which versions of each are you using? If you get into the fiddle I posted you can copy the links from cdn and open in the browser, you'll have the code, download it and use the `<script>` and `<link>` tags in the same order that is in the fiddle and it should work

Comment: Also I suggest a newer version of jquery, since you are using 1.10 and the current one is 3.1

Comment: I found the mistake. Sorry for wasting your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I caught the error.
I had a previous jquery link in the _Layout view.

Thanks everyone for helping me.